# Ubuntu Touch Installation stucks at "Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting"

Tags: ubuntu-touch

)

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu Touch on my 'Huawei Ascend G510'. I have already unlocked it. Because of the command 'sudo fastboot devices' I know that my phone is connected. But when I try to install Ubuntu Touch (ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap) it stucks at the message: Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting

What can I do? :(

Sincerley, SevoX

Comment: Seems to be a bug affecting many users: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phablet-tools/+bug/1455050